# Como configurar a localização do diretório de trabalho no Git?

Tags: git

Ao instalar o Git, não consegui configurar a localização do meu diretório de trabalho.

Já alterei para "Iniciar em:"C:\Users\Renata Mendes\Documents\Projetos"" nas propriedades do Git Bash, mas a alteração não fica salva e toda vez que inicializo o terminal tenho que entrar manualmente no diretório.

Qual a melhor maneira de se fazer isso?

P.S: Sou iniciante em Git e em Programação.

Comment: "Qual" Git você instalou? Exemplo: [git-scm](http://git-scm.com/downloads), [Tortoise git](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/wiki/Download), etc.. O que você quer dizer com "localização do meu diretório de trabalho"? Você só possui um único repositório git na sua máquina e quer que a janela prompt do git abra sempre no caminho desse repositório? Ou é alguma outra coisa que eu não entendi?

Answer (score 6):

Olá,

Consegui alterar o caminho inicial do git bash alterando o parâmetro 'iniciar em' nas propriedades, aqui deu certo, acho que o problema que você esta tendo é por causa do caractere espaço. Tente utilizar um caminho sem espaço para testar.

[image: Imagem das propriedades do git bash]

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Editei sua resposta para remover as saudações pois costumamos manter o texto o mais limpo possível para focar na sua resposta sobre programação. Caso tenha interesse em visitar uma parte do site que não é voltado para tirar dúvidas pode conhecer o [chat]. Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o [meta] :)

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Tente seguir estes passos:

1- Campo destino : remover oque estiver depois das aspas, deixando apenas a até a terminação "xxxxxx\Git\git-bash.exe" nada além disso.

2- Campo iniciar em: Colocar a pasta o atalho que deseja que seja inicializado o programa.

Dessa forma ao reabrir o Git Bash ele já irá estar configurado com o caminho indicado no campo 2.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Editei sua resposta para remover as saudações pois costumamos manter o texto o mais limpo possível para focar na sua resposta sobre programação. Caso tenha interesse em visitar uma parte do site que não é voltado para tirar dúvidas pode conhecer o [chat]. Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o [meta] :)